# How to get into into another child than 'firstChild' of XML file in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xml-documentation

How can I get through another child of XML file than firstChild in PHP?
I have a code like this:

```
        $root = $xmldoc->firstChild;
```

Can I simply get into second child or another?

Comment: How does your xml structure look like? Please give a more detailed example und explain, what the node is called you want tp get. PHP holds several methods for fetching XML nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a structure like this:

    <xmldata>
    <data>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    </data>
    </xmldata>

By my code *$root = $xmldoc->firstChild;* I can access into >xmldata<, but I would like to add something into >data< which is a second child of XML file. How can I do that?

Comment: By definition, in a well-formed XML document [there is only one root element](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-root), in your example `xmldata`; the element `data` **is not the second child of the XML file**, it's the first child of the root element (and of course the root element, and each other element, can have several children).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution to your problem could be something like this. First your XML structure. You asked how to add an item node to the data node.

```
$xml = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xmldata>
    <data>
        <item>item 1</item>
        <item>item 2</item>
    </data>
</xmldata>
XML;
```

In PHP one possible solution is the DomDocument object.

```
$doc = new \DomDocument();
$doc->loadXml($xml);

// fetch data node
$dataNode = $doc->getElementsByTagName('data')->item(0);

// create new item node
$newItemNode = $doc->createElement('item', 'item 3');

// append new item node to data node
$dataNode->appendChild($newItemNode);

// save xml node
$doc->saveXML();
```

This code example is not tested. Have fun. ;)

Comment: $root = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('data')->item(0);
Thanks that works :)